# How to display "Application is down for upgrade" message when redeploying Glassfish application?

Tags: deployment, glassfish

I tried to access a web application while it was in the process of redeploying or reloading, and I just got a 404 error. This is likely to result in time-wasting helpdesk calls if a user happens to see it. How can I replace the 404 message with something more helpful, like "This application is being upgraded - check back in a minute or two"?

Comment: I normally deploy my webapps behind an Apache proxy. When the appserver goes down Apache returns a 503 response. This can be customised I think with an alternative "I'm sorry we're doing maintanence" message

Comment: @MarkO'Connor You should post that as an answer, it sounds perfect!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider looking at Application Versioning feature to "pre-deploy" an application to minimize the impact.

Deploy your app:
$ asadmin deploy myapp.war

Deploy version2 in "disabled" mode, meaning the old version is still active:
$ asadmin deploy --enabled=false --name myapp:version2 myapp.war  (version2 is an arbitrary name)

When ready to activate version2:
$ asadmin enable myapp:version2

The nice thing about this approach is that if you run into issues with version2, you can always fall back to the original version:

$ asadmin enable myapp

Answer (score 0):

I normally deploy my webapps behind an [Apache proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html). When the appserver goes down Apache returns a 503 response.

This can be [customised](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/503-header-apache-htaccess/) with an alternative "I'm sorry we're doing maintanence" message

Answer (score 0):

You can also customize the standard response codes (403, 404, etc.) in the server configuration.  The simple change is to change the message text, but it isn't as elegant as what you are looking for.  However, there will always be a point where the environment will return 404, 503, etc., so you might consider adding this, in addition to, the "behind the proxy" answer provided by @Mark O'Connor.